# Foreign key issue when adding user to role with SimpleMembership (MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys, simplemembership

I'm trying to use SimpleMembership with MySQL in a Code First project. This is the initializer I made:

```
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyConnectionStringName", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", false);

        if (!Roles.RoleExists("Employee"))
        {
            Roles.CreateRole("Employee");
        }

        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("Kurt"))
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("Kurt", "test");
            Roles.AddUserToRole("Kurt", "Employee");
        }
```

The following exception appears by `AddUserToRole`:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ticket`.`webpages_usersinroles`, CONSTRAINT `fk_RoleId` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleId`) REFERENCES `webpages_roles` (`RoleId`))

The user is added to the table `userprofile` (and `webpages_membership`) and the role to `webpages_roles`. `webpages_usersinroles` is still empty. MySQL can't reference the role because of a mysterious reason. How do I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First exec set foreign_key_checks=0;
execute your query
again set foreign_key_checks=1;

Answer (score 0):

However, when using the API to programmatically add users and roles, you need to make sure your database already has the database schema required by the application services. Fortunately, again this is pretty easy to do. In the sample application you find code that looks like this:

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/563/using-entity-framework-code-first-and-aspnet-membership-together